# SQLite query for combining where, oder by and union all

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I Have this two tables as shown in SQLite database.
I'm working on android studio.

TableMain

```
TASK         TIME    DATE
GO TO GYM.   12:30   18-3-2020
CALL MOM.    13:40   18-3-2020
MEETING.     20:20   19-3-2020
```

TableRoutine

```
TASK         TIME   
DINNER       14:30   
KEY          18:40
```

I need the result like this: where I get 2 columns TASK TIME 
So I used union all.

For order by I used Time column

```
TASK.        TIME   
GO TO GYM.   12:30   
CALL MOM.    13:40   
DINNER       14:30   
KEY          18:40
```

QUERY:

```
SELECT Task
     , Time 
  FROM TableMain 
 UNION ALL 
SELECT Task
     , Time 
  FROM TableRoutine 
 Where Tablemain.Date = "18-3-2020" 
 Order 
    By Time
```

I need only task which is of 18-3-2020
But it doesn't working.
Because I didn't take the Date column in the SELECT statement error is generating.

So what should I do?

Comment: If you just want records for .Date = "18-3-2020" then how would you select from TableRoutine ? TableRoutine does not contain date column

Comment: `"18-3-2020"` seems not to be correct date literal for SQLite. Use `'2020-03-18'` instead.

Comment: Ya. you are correct. you understand my problem. But now that should I write where i TableMain task with provided date and all task of TableRoutine.

Comment: I'm storing date as string as per my requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to shift where clause above:

```
SELECT Task
     , Time 
FROM TableMain
Where Tablemain.Date = '18-3-2020'  
UNION ALL 
SELECT Task
 , Time 
FROM TableRoutine 
Order By Time
```